# Is it possible to run kubectl port-forward in Terraform null_resource block

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, hashicorp-vault

Is there any way to do port-forwarding in the middle of processing using Terraform providers without getting stuck?

Here's what I'd do in terminal for installing Bank Vaults, port forward into the Vault pod, and import data from a json file, then create a secret or config map based on the imported data.

Reference: https://banzaicloud.com/docs/bank-vaults/installing/#deploy-operator

```
kubectl apply -f vault-cr.yaml

kubectl port-forward vault-0 8200 &

vault kv put -format=json secret/path @/tmp/var.json

kubectl apply -f secret.yaml
```

This Terraform code won't work because it is getting stuck in the `import_vault_data` resource block.

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "some_app" {
  
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "bank_vaults" {
  yaml_body = <<YAML
# vault manifest
YAML
}

resource "null_resource" "import_vault_data" {
  depends_on = [kubectl_manifest.bank_vaults]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "kubectl port-forward vault-0 8200 & sleep 15 && vault kv put -format=json secret/path @/tmp/var.json"
  }
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "some_secret" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.import_vault_data]
  yaml_body = <<YAML
# secret manifest
YAML
}
```

I've also tried Terragrunt's `before hook` and `after hook` but they also have the same issue. (Related discussion: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/856#issuecomment-530091210)

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the [Terraform Vault provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs) here instead of shelling out the Vault CLI?

Comment: I will try the Vault provider way tomorrow. The reason I did’t use Vault provider in the first place was that the vault CLI allows me to do the K8s deployment in single run. With Vault provider, it requires separate execution and code splitting.

Comment: Why do you think that's the case?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/812